# Sympy's Simplify function does not appear to simplify Rational numbers by removing common factors

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to use Sympy to define repeating decimal fractions using geometric series. In particular, I am trying to find the sequence limit (not partial sum limit) at infinity. My code work for simple cases, like:

.33333333 + ...

but when I try to do it for a more complicated case, like:

.400840084008 + ...

my code fails to calculate the sequence limit. When I troubleshoot my code, I get a very strange result  for rational number, a, in the geometric series: geo_series = a*(r**n).  My code is:

```
import numpy as np

import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Figure

from sympy import limit_seq, lambdify, simplify, Symbol, Rational, Dummy

def seq_limit(seq, n):

   try:

        n_ = Dummy("n", integer=True, positive=True)

        L1 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n_), n_)
        if L1 is None:
            print('Sympy evaluates sequence limit, L1, to None')
            return np.NaN

        L2 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n_ + 1), n_)
        if L2 is None:
           print('Sympy evaluates sequence limit, L2, to None')
           return np.NaN
    except:
        return np.NaN

    if L1 == L2 :
        return L1
    else:
        print('L1 (even terms):', L1)
        print('L2 (odd terms):', L2)
        return np.NaN


def sum_limit(a, r):

    if np.absolute(r) >= 1 and a != 0:
        return np.NaN
    elif a == 0:
        return 0
    elif np.absolute(r) < 1:
        return a/(1 - r)


def geo_term_eval(func, i):

    term = lambdify(n, func)

    if term is None:
        print('Cannot evaluate a lambdified term')
    return term(i)


class Sequence(object):

    def __init__(self,geo_term, i):

        self.geo_term = geo_term
        self.sum = 0
        self.partial_sum = np.array([])
        self.dom = np.arange(i)
        self.rng = np.array([])
        self.is_positive = True
        self.is_alternating = True

        for i in self.dom:
            rng_val = geo_term_eval(self.geo_term, i)
            self.rng = np.append(self.rng, [rng_val])
            self.sum += rng_val
            self.partial_sum = np.append(self.partial_sum, [self.sum])

        sign_array = np.sign(self.rng)

        for i in self.dom:

            if self.rng[i] <= 0:
                self.is_positive = False
                break

        for i in self.dom[:-1]:

            if sign_array[i] == sign_array[i + 1]:
                self.is_alternating = False
                break

        self.seq_limit = seq_limit(geo_term, n)
        self.sum_limit = float(sum_limit(a, r))

        if self.seq_limit != np.NaN:
            self.seq_converges = True
        else:
            self.seq_converges = False

        if self.sum_limit != np.NaN:
            self.sum_converges = True
    else:
            self.sum_converges = False


py.sign_in('****', '***************')

a = Rational(501, 1250)  # same as Rational(4008, 10000)
r = Rational(1,-10000)

n = Symbol('n')
n_terms = 10
geo_term = simplify(a*r**n)

seq = Sequence(geo_term, n_terms)

if seq.seq_limit == np.NaN:
   print('Seq Limit:', 'None')
else:
   print ('Seq limit: ', seq.seq_limit)

if seq.sum_limit == np.NaN:
   print('Sum Limit', 'None')
else:
   print ('Sum limit: ', seq.sum_limit)

data = [Scatter(x=seq.dom, y=seq.rng)]
fig = Figure(data=data)

py.image.save_as(fig, filename='plots/geo_seq.png')

data = [Scatter(x=seq.dom, y=seq.partial_sum)]
fig = Figure(data=data)

py.image.save_as(fig, filename='plots/geo_sum.png')
```

The rational ratio which Sympy calculates for Rational(4008, 10000) or Rational(501, 1250) is: 7220170922600379/18014398509481984
which I believe is the source of the problem when trying to calculate the limit. Any help will be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Do you want `Rational(501, 1250)` instead of `Rational(501/1250)`, maybe?

Comment: You might want to change your credentials, now that they have been exposed and will always be visible in the question history, at least to a great many users around here who even can view deleted questions etc.

Comment: That for catching the typo, but it did not change the issue when I corrected and reran the code.

Comment: Btw, this credential problem only happened because you made several mistakes: ① You pasted your complete code.  You should have created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead. ② You put your credentials in the code in the first place.  It's always better to use code which reads the credentials from a secured file instead. `with open('credentials') as f: py.sign_in(*f.read().split())` or similar.

Comment: Re your original question.  That `simplify(a*r**n)` results in `501*(-1/10000)**n/1250` for me, that's the same as for `a*r**n`, so `simplify()` doesn't change it.  But it seems to be correct to me.  What did you expect instead?

Comment: Also thanks for catching the credential issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the correct way to set up credentials, I will do from now on. as for the origanal issue I am getting 7220170922600379*(-1/10000)**n/18014398509481984.  I am using python 3.5 with anaconda

Comment: Show a rational number that `simplify` does not simplify: like `simplify(...)` -> unsimplified answer. I doubt you can. The fact that you posted this wall of code instead of isolating the part that's causing a problem shows you don't know where the problem is. No [mcve], voting to close.

Comment: @LH66 I got those strange large numbers when I created `Rational(501/1250)` instead of `Rational(501, 1250)`.  Did you really fix this?

Comment: Actually I resolved the issue. I had two debuggers open in pycharm and was looking at the wrong debugger. You are correct.  I also found the issue  with the problem calculation of the limit of the sequence which was caused by the statements:   L1 = limit_seq(seq.subs(n, 2*n_), n_)  it needed to be changed to:   L1 = limit_seq(simplify(seq.subs(n, 2*n_)), n_). L2 needed to be changed similiarly.

Comment: Also, I had to add a second version of the function: geo_term_float = a*(Float(r)**n)  as an argument for the function, geo_term_eval. This allows for the function to be evaluated for when r is eother negative or positive.  I am very happy with the code because now I have a general solution.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was a simple syntax problem:  r= Rational(501/1250) needed to be changed to r = Rational(501, 1250). When the division is done first, then the Rational function calculates a non simplified ratio which although is correct but causes problem when the other Sympy functions are called.

Comment: I don't believe that any one that votes something down, without a comment does not deserve any credibility. Rational(501/1250) -> 7220170922600379/18014398509481984 in Sympy.